# Why I am not able to print first element in this Linked List?

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, data-structures, linked-list

> You are given two non-empty linked lists representing two non-negative integers. The digits are stored in reverse order and each of their nodes contain a single digit. Add the two numbers and return it as a linked list.

> Example:

```
Input: (2 -> 4 -> 3) + (5 -> 6 -> 4)
Output: 7 -> 0 -> 8
Explanation: 342 + 465 = 807

    class Solution {
    public:
        ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
            
            vector<int> a1;
            vector<int> a2;
            vector<int> result;
            while(l1->next||l2->next)
            {
                a1.push_back(l1->val);
                a2.push_back(l2->val);
                l1=l1->next;
                l2=l2->next;
            }
            int v1=0;
            int v2=0;
            for(auto d:a1)
            {
                v1=v1*10+d;
                
            }
            for(auto f:a2)
            {
                v2=v2*10+f;
            }
            int v3=v1+v2;
            int r;
            while(v3>0)
            {
                r=v3%10;
                v3=v3/10;
                result.push_back(r);
                
            }
            ListNode* p= new ListNode(result[0]);
            ListNode* start=p;
            ListNode* add=p;
            int i;
            for(i=1;i<result.size();i++)
            {
                ListNode* temp=new ListNode(result[i]);
                
                add->next=temp;
                add=add->next;
            }
            return p;
        }
    };

Output(1st element of the linked list is not printing)

Input: [2,4,3]
       [5,6,4]
               
Your answer:[0,8]              
Expected answer:[7,0,8]
```

> I am not able to print the first element of the resultant linked list. I Tried with different test cases and its printing everything right except the first element.

Comment: `for(i=1; ...` --> `for(i=0; ...`?

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening. Knowing how to use a debugger is a required skill for every C++ developer, no exceptions. With your debugger's help you should be able to quickly find all bugs in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Comment: when i change i=0,its printing 0 at the start @cigien

Comment: sure i will give it a try now @SamVarshavchik

Answer (score 0):

```
        while(l1->next||l2->next)
        {
            a1.push_back(l1->val);
            a2.push_back(l2->val);
            l1=l1->next;
            l2=l2->next;
        }
```

This will crash if `l1` and `l2` have different lengths. It will continue looping once a list is done. But, in the immediate the issue is that the last element has:

- valid `l1->val`
- null `l1->next`

So, for the last element, you will not push into `a1` and/or `a2`.

If you are sure you have identical length, then you could simply:

```
        while(l1 || l2)
        {
            a1.push_back(l1->val);
            a2.push_back(l2->val);
            l1=l1->next;
            l2=l2->next;
        }
```

Comment: yeah that can be a tweak but the input i am dealing with have the same length, i tried your approach too but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not considering the carry. If the sum of last digits of two numbers > 9, additional node needs to be created.